# WinForms ListView smooth scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll

*Windows Explorer* is able to display semi-visible items when scrolling. This behaviour produces a smooth scrolling.

Is there a way to reproduce this effect with the `ListView` in Windows Forms?

[image: Windows Explorer view]

**Update**

I found by change another `ListView` with same behaviour:

[image: Properties Windows dialog]

Comment: Explorer does not use a ListView.  It is custom control, a subclassed DirectUIHwnd.  Looks and feels a lot like ListView but the content is completely custom-painted, the rough equivalent to ListView.OwnerDraw.  Which is why it can pull tricks like this.  Microsoft does not want to share it with us.

Comment: I found another list in Windows properties dialog displaying the same effect. According to WinSpy++ it is a `SysListView32`.

Comment: That one is more convincing.  Work in Winforms as well but you have to use the Groups property.

Comment: I tried to apply groups in a virtual mode ListView and it wasn't working because this isn't implemented by default (it is an undocumented feature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to scroll by a partial line is not generally a useful feature.

However, if you really want to be able to do it, just set `ShowGroups` to `true`. The ListView control will then allow pixel level scrolling.

For example:

[image: example of pixel level scrolling]